# jQuery Draggable doesn't work with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

The following is a block of javascript I wrote:

```
$(function(){
$("#schoolBagBtn").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:"./php/get.php",
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#schoolBagList").html(data);
        $(".schoolBagListItem").draggable();
    });

});
});
```

The ajax function is work fine and the HTML code inside the #schoolBagList is changed.
However, the `$(".schoolBagListItem").draggable();` doesn't work.
Every time, I run this javascript, A Error message `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at line 8` is shown in the console log.

The following is the data returned from the ajax call.

```
<li id="CRS00001" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">ITP4505</li>
<li data-link="./emptyTeachingBook.pdf" id="MAT00001" class="list-group-item col-sm-offset-1 schoolBagListItem">Empty Teaching Book</li>
<li id="CRS00002" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">ITP4506</li>
<li id="FDR00000" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Testing Folder 1</li>
<li data-link="./testingLink.pdf" id="FIL00000" class="list-group-item col-sm-offset-1 schoolBagListItem">Empty File 1</li>
<li id="FDR00001" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Testing Folder 2</li>
<li data-link="./emptyFile2.pdf" id="FIL00002" class="list-group-item col-sm-offset-1 schoolBagListItem">Empty File 2</li>
<li data-link="./file/251826_483198608361706_766265894_n.jpg" id="FIL00003" class="list-group-item col-sm-offset-1 schoolBagListItem">251826_483198608361706_766265894_n.jpg</li>
<li id="FDR00009" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">A</li><li data-link="./file/Beautiful-Water-Line.jpg" id="FIL00005" class="list-group-item col-sm-offset-1 schoolBagListItem">Beautiful-Water-Line.jpg</li>
<li data-link="./file/65377_600883856649979_72587957_n.jpg" id="FIL00006" class="list-group-item col-sm-offset-1 schoolBagListItem">65377_600883856649979_72587957_n.jpg</li>
<li id="FDR00010" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">B</li>
<li id="FDR00011" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">C</li><li id="FDR00015" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Test</li>
<li id="FDR00016" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Test</li>
<li id="FDR00017" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Test</li>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you included jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes, of cuz. It will work, if I delete the ajax block

Comment: are you sure the schoolBagListItem class is present in the response of ajax ?

Comment: Yes, it is present in the response of ajax. And it will work, if I change the draggable function to show/hide function.

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward here is the simple demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrfLS/). And the data returned from the ajax, I will post in the question. Thanks a lot ^^

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ZrfLS/1/; are you sure that the ajax call is not raising an error?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward
Yes, I am sure the call is not raising an error, since the content of the $("#schoolBagList") has been updated successfully.